# How can I set up additional email folders on my Galaxy S3?

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-3

On my Samsung Galaxy S3 I can see the standard folders: inbox, drafts, outbox, sent, recycle.
How do I set up additional folders?

Comment: Please specify the email app you refer to -- otherwise it's hard to tell. If you don't know it, at least give some more details on your device, e.g. manufacturer and Android version. Not everybody knows what an S111 is (I don't, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, eldarerathis! I thought the OP could have meant the Galaxy S3 but wasn't sure. One should refrain from using "fancy writing" when looking for help (little hint to the Captain :)